# How to add a background image to an item in a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I want to add a background image to an item in a navigation drawer.

**What I currently have:**

[image: What I currently have(Image)]

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

On each column there would be a background image. I'm going to remove the text and just fill items with images. Is this possible? If yes, do I need different resolutions for background images?

**activity_main_drawer.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM1"
            android:title="@string/ITEM1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM2"
            android:title="@string/ITEM2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ITEM3"
            android:title="@string/ITEM3" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. Fixed the tags.

Comment: you have to customize the drawer with ListView or RecyclerView